# Hierarchical query outputs error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
  with tbl as
  (
    Select parent_b.BRANCH_ID, parent_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           parent_b.BRANCH, parent_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID
    from table parent_b
    Where parent_b.branch_Id = 1
    UNION ALL
    Select child_b.BRANCH_ID, child_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           child_b.BRANCH, child_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID
    from table child_b 
    INNER JOIN tbl parent
        ON parent.branch_id = child_b.branch_id
  )
  select * from tbl
 OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Above code gets me error with this message:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion.

I checked the table, and there no rows where row points to himself (infinity).

Where is my problem?

Comment: I thiink the error is pretty clear.  Either you have a logical flaw in your coding or you need the `MAXRECURSION` option (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I tried with it, but not succesfully. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a logical error in the recursive part of your CTE - the join condition:

```
ON parent.branch_id = child_b.branch_id
```

is linking the parent's `branch_id` directly to the child's `branch_id`, when it should be linking to the child's `parent_branch_id` - like so:

```
ON parent.branch_id = child_b.parent_branch_id
```

The following query should work:

```
 with tbl as
  (
    Select parent_b.BRANCH_ID, parent_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           parent_b.BRANCH, parent_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID
    from table parent_b
    Where parent_b.branch_Id = 1
    UNION ALL
    Select child_b.BRANCH_ID, child_b.BRANCH_CODE,
           child_b.BRANCH, child_b.PARENT_BRANCH_ID
    from table child_b 
    INNER JOIN tbl parent
        ON parent.branch_id = child_b.parent_branch_id
  )
  select * from tbl
 OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the maxrecursion option at the end of the query:

```
 select *
from tbl
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Your query is not output me `error message`, but your query outputs only element with `branch_Id = 1`.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш please check your query and data. You can specify data example